# windows workflow bookmark

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I do this workflow with bookmark

```
namespace wwwfff
{

    public sealed class CodeActivity3 : NativeActivity
    {
        public InArgument<string> EventName1

        { get; set; }



        public OutArgument<string> Data1

        { get; set; }



        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {

            context.CreateBookmark(EventName1.Get(context), new BookmarkCallback(HandleEvent));
            Console.WriteLine("Pppppppppppp");
        }



        private void HandleEvent(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object obj)
        {

            if (obj != null)
            {

                Data1.Set(context, obj.ToString());

            }

        }
    }
}
```

*and i write in program*

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkflowApplication wf = new WorkflowApplication(new Workflow1());
            wf.Run();
           wf.ResumeBookmark("C1", "Hello word");

        }
    }
```

but it doesn't type "ppppppp" 
the workflow is only start `->CodeActivity3->writline()`
thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need probably override property in CodeActivity3 class

```
protected override bool CanInduceIdle { get { return true; } }
```